Is it safe to eat yellow yam, which I pan-fried?
in re yellow yam, it would seem to be generally said (every article or video I googled) that
(A) if you touch it (either skin or guts of it) during prep, your hands will break out, wear heavy gloves. (I didn't, because I live dangerously, and I'm rarely affected by that sort of thing, and indeed i got "tingly hands" and
(B) you have to boil it a lot (usually claiming "with salt and lime") before it is edible. (Presumably, if it hurts your hands to touch it, you can't put it in your mouth or eg. stomach - but IDK.)
Instead of boiling I pan fried it (for a long time), just with some citrus and salt (skin completely cut off).
Am I in trouble?
I couldn't find a straight answer anywhere whether
(A) you must boil it ("with salt and lime") to avoid some sort of harmful agent or,
(B), they're just making the point that it's a food that tastes like crap unless you boil it a lot to get rid of all taste.
IDK

PS got impatient; I took my life in my hands and tried one

no ill effects (...yet)

quite bitter, not pleasantly so. I won't eat the rest. perhaps it's a known thing that they must be boiled?

before frying I washed down, scrubbed, the slices with lots of water and mandarin pieces (no lime in the fridge); I have no idea if this is worthy: seen on the Jamaican internet.


Pic:

Random one of 100s of pics on the internet of "yellow yam for sale in a supermarket"

eg,
https://www.specialtyproduce.com/produce/Yellow_Name_Root_14017.php
this one is exactly the brand I bought, notice the small label attached with a band (the label says "Yellow Yam"

Random video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4S15HnqP5rU (they're all similar)

Can you explain more about this "yellow yam"?  Most varieties of yam do not need to be boiled to be safe to eat.  What are you cooking, exactly?

Fuzz, apparently sometimes called Jamaican Yam ?  (Titled "yellow yam" in this Southern US location supermarket. I knew nothing of it.)  If you just search (as I learned) say "Jamaican Yellow Yam" you will find innumerable references (I did not know this and had never heard of it or seen it before)

There's a bunch of different varieties of yam, and sweet potato, many of which are yellow.  The term "Jamaican yellow yam" does not seem to correspond to any generally-agreed-on variety.  So none of us can know what you actually bought.

FWIW from the picture, the bitterness could well be burned sugars as some of those pieces are well and truly blackened

Oddly enough the last picture looks like the end result is orange - from the image on the label. There are orange yams too, though they tend to be the "American yam" (sweet potato, Ipomea batatas), which this isn't - the tubers are quite different between Yam and sweet potato.

@bob1 indeed they start (when you cut them) a milky white color, and after cooking seem to be orange (as seen even in my pan photo).  I never saw any yellow! You not yellow, mon.

I assume you are referring to the Jamaican Yellow Yam.
From a perspective of food safety: It does not contain any harmful chemical compounds that need to be neutralized or otherwise rendered safe through prolonged boiling. So it is safe to eat.
But for people with weak digestion, it is advised to boil or otherwise cook the yams or other such tubers well to make it easier to digestion.
It is similar to asking if sweet potato can be eaten raw or boiled or fried.
Eating it raw is a very bad idea and will significantly tax the digestive system, with some people developing abdominal pain or discomfort.
Boiling or cooking (including frying, as in sweet potato fries) breaks down the starches into compounds which are much more easily digested by humans.
So in the end, there is no health risk. Just personal preferences.

Thanks.  Yes the usual recommendation is to boil but I didn't do that, I pan fried.  As the Q says "Instead of boilding I pan fried it..."

This seems just to be a member of the regular yam family, probably  the species Dioscorea cayenensis.
As far as I can tell, it should be fine to eat raw, but will taste better cooked. You should be able to cook it in any manner that you like. I see recipes for yams that include boiling, frying, and roasting as common methods for cooking.

It's generally said (every single article or video I googled) that (A) if you touch it (either skin or guts of it) during prep, your hands will break out, wear heavy gloves.  (I didn't, because I live dangerously, and I'm rarely affected by that sort of thing, and indeed i got "tingly hands" and (B) you have to boil it a lot (usually claiming "with salt and lime") before it is edible.  IDK

Also apparently "yellow neeahmay" is yet another name used.

@Fattie it will depend on exactly which species it is. Some of the species within the family are quite toxic, but others are fine to eat raw. I believe this is one of the ones that is OK, but it definitely depends on the species. From what I see online, people feed the peelings and leaves of the species I mentioned to cattle, so we can probably eat them too, though some discomfort (prickly in throat) and bitter taste from saponins present in the skin.

@Fattie I can't find any reliable links for the species of yellow neeahmay - it doesn't return much in my DuckDuckGo search at all, though adding "yam" to that helps. They are lily family, which does include some quite toxic members, so I wouldn't be surprised if mildly toxic.
